# Reliably set working directory for python application

Tags: python

I am making a small application that I will invite some users to test for me. I have been developing in PyCharm, and running the program from the dev directory, and the issue of a working directory just recently came to my mind.

The program and all files are contained in the project directory. Naturally, I want the working directory to be the project directory, regardless of where the user decides to store the program.

What is the most reliable way of achieving this? I was thinking something like this

```
import os

dir_work = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
```

and then set all paths relative to `dir_work`. Is there a better way? I have also been thinking of making a setup script that the user can edit, and that when run hardcodes some stuff into the source code. But if my problem can be achieved without user intervention, that would definitely be the best solution.

Comment: Indeed, you are right!

Comment: yes that is probably the most reliable way to find the directory where the file is located

Comment: Are you looking for something akin to ˋpkg_resourcesˋ perhaps?